# Is it possible to stub a file upload using the Ruby AWS SDK?

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

Going off what I found in the [AWS Developers Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-ruby/latest/DeveloperGuide/aws-ruby-sdk-programming.html) and looking at their [API Docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html) it looks like I should be able to stub `upload_file` natively. However the following does not work and `upload_file` simply returns `true`

```
client = Aws::S3::Client.new(stub_responses: true)
client.stub_responses(:upload_file, false)

resource = Aws::S3::Resource.new(client: client)
obj = resource.bucket('foo').object('bar')

obj.upload_file(Tempfile.new('tmp')) #=> `true` when I want `false`
```

The [API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/ClientStubs.html) refers to the first argument of `stub_responses` as `operation_name`. The examples often use operation named `list_buckets` and sometimes `head_bucket` but I cannot find a list of operations that are acceptable. Am I reading the docs wrong or setting up the example wrong?

#### Workaround

As a work around I'm using RSpec to stub the method. Assuming I get the same object in `obj`, the above example just needs the following for my test to pass

```
allow(obj).to receive(:upload_file).and_return(false)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a quick look at the Api docs you pointed, my best guess is that the `stub_response` is only stubbing the method calls that go directly on `client` which is an instance of `Aws::S3::Client` class.

However, you do `upload_file` on an instance of `Aws::S3::Object` for which `client.stub_reponses` wouldn't stub the method.

Comment: This is correct, the `stub_response` is only defined on the `Client` class and not on the `Resource` class. You could use WebMock to stub the HTTP request or encapsulate the file upload on a method that you can stub.

Comment: Thanks for confirming @EdgarOrtega